# Stack layers don't perfectly overlap

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile, widget

Good morning, I'm trying to build a compounded filter widget where the left side is a DropDown and the right side a TextField. They are attached side by side and divided by a small separator. When they have focus, only the current selected filter must be highlighted (focusBordered property).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Here my current code and some screenshots.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum WorkpieceStatus {
  all,
  completed,
  in_progress,
  to_do,
}

extension WorkpieceStatusExt on WorkpieceStatus {
  String get text {
    switch (this) {
      case WorkpieceStatus.all:
        return 'all';
      case WorkpieceStatus.completed:
        return 'completed';
      case WorkpieceStatus.in_progress:
        return 'in progress';
      case WorkpieceStatus.to_do:
        return 'to do';
      default:
        return 'unknown';
    }
  }

  Color get color {
    switch (this) {
      case WorkpieceStatus.all:
        return Color(0xFF000000);
      case WorkpieceStatus.completed:
        return Color(0xFF37A600);
      case WorkpieceStatus.in_progress:
        return Color(0xFF0097E0);
      case WorkpieceStatus.to_do:
        return Color(0xFF717171);
      default:
        return Colors.red;
    }
  }
}

class FilterBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const FilterBox({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FilterBox> createState() => _FilterBoxState();
}

class _FilterBoxState extends State<FilterBox> {
  final List<WorkpieceStatus> values = [
    WorkpieceStatus.all,
    WorkpieceStatus.completed,
    WorkpieceStatus.in_progress,
    WorkpieceStatus.to_do,
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildGroundLayer(),
        _buildInputLayer(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGroundLayer() {
    return Container(
      height: 55.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        border: Border.all(
          width: 2.5,
          color: Color(0xFFD2D2D2),
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(27.0),
      ),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: SizedBox(),
          ),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minWidth: 2.0,
              maxWidth: 2.0,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 7.5,
              ),
              child: VerticalDivider(
                thickness: 2.0,
                color: Color(0xFFD2D2D2),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: SizedBox(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInputLayer() {
    return Container(
      height: 55.0,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: _buildDropDownField(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: _buildSearchField(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDropDownField() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      elevation: 12,
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.expand_more,
        size: 24.0,
        color: Color(0xFF2E2E2E),
      ),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: 2.5,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(27.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(27.0),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xFFFF7321),
            width: 2.5,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(27.0),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(27.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      hint: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 12.0,
        ),
        child: Text(
          'Status',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: Color(0xFFA6A6A6),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      items: values
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
            (WorkpieceStatus status) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: status.text,
              child: Text(
                status.text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: status.color,
                  fontFamily: 'RobotoFlex-Regular',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (String? value) => print(value),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchField() {
    return TextField(
      cursorColor: Color(0xFF131415),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            width: 2.5,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(27.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(27.0),
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xFFFF7321),
            width: 2.5,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(27.0),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(27.0),
          ),
        ),
        prefixIcon: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          size: 24.0,
          color: Color(0xFF2E2E2E),
        ),
        hintText: 'Search by UII',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          color: Color(0xFFA6A6A6),
        ),
      ),
      onChanged: (String value) => print(value),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like that both inputs cover the little VerticalDivider Widget at the bottom when they are on the focus state, so that they give the illusion they are the same component. It seems that the DropDown field doesn't extend so far to cover it.

[Screenshots - Expected and Result](https://postimg.cc/gallery/QBG8Ysb)

Comment: can you add the screenshot of what you got and what you expected?

Comment: Yes, sure. I added a link to some screenshots gallery.